# Type of table in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I'm trying to reproduce this table and am having difficulty.

[image]

What I tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{3cm}}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{10.5cm}|s| }
    \hline
    L'ensemble des polynômes de degré inférieur ou égal à $n$ & Notation : $\mathscr{P}_n$ ou $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$P \in \mathscr{P}_n$ signifie que $P$ est un polynôme de degré inférieur ou égal à $n$} \\
    $(\forall (P, Q) \in \mathscr{P}_n^2) \quad (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \quad \begin{cases}
            (P + Q)(x) = P(x) + Q(x) \\
            (P \times Q)(x) = P(x) \times Q(x)
        \end{cases}$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What I obtain

[image]

Comment: Your table is very different from the image you provide, so it isn't clear at all what you want.  For example the text in your code is different from the text in the image, and you don't have any matrices in your code. Instead you have a predicate. You also don't specify what your difficulty is. Please be clear about what you want.

Comment: Off-topic: No need to load both `amssymb` and `latexsym`. In fact, *don't* load `latexsym`.

Comment: In fact I don't want a vertical bar on the second line.

Comment: In my table there is a bar that is incorrectly placed even though I did not put & in the second line of my code.
For the text I want to put any text it doesn't matter so it's not a problem.

Comment: May be it's easier to see your problem, once you added a screenshot of your codes result? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,calc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm} % '1mm' seems to be too much
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75} % '2.5' seems to be too much
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{%
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.62\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.38\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} }
\hline
L'ensemble des polynômes de degré inférieur ou égal à $n$ & 
Notation: $\mathscr{P}_n$ ou $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ \\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gainsboro} % a bit lighter than "lightgray" 
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{%
$P\in\mathscr{P}_n$ signifie que $P$ est un polynôme de degré inférieur ou égal à $n$ 

\[
  \forall (P, Q) \in \mathscr{P}_n^2) \quad 
      (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \quad 
      \left\{ \begin{aligned}
                &(P + Q)(x) = P(x) + Q(x) \\
                &(P \times Q)(x) = P(x) \times Q(x)
      \end{aligned} \right.
\] } \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you separate the two texts of the first line with a vertical bar?

Comment: @Dots - I've updated the code to insert a vertical bar between the columns.